# Running Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm trying to run a copy of symfony on my website, but am getting

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BaseSettings' not found in /home/firefly/web/firefly.com/public/htdocs/sandbox/fireflyproject/project/lib/model/doctrine/Settings.class.php on line 13
```

I tried googling it but got zero results,  any clue what might be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: 13 directories deep? Seriously? But on a different note, can you describe your installation procedure?

Comment: @RafeKettler This is Symfony; 13 directories deep is *nothing* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you forgot to generate your model files. If you're on 1.3 or 1.4 version, you have to use the command line and do :
./symfony doctrine:build --all

And you might also have to clear the cache : ./symfony cc

Answer (score 3):

My analysis is I guess you're using Windows for your localhost, and your website server using Linux/Unix. Try to see your database table (e.g. MySQL), if your database table name uses lowercase letter, then go the

```
lib/model/doctrine(or propel)/base/BaseSettings.class.php
```

. There is code like `$this->setTableName('[name_of_your_setting_table]');` Check it, [name_of_your_setting_table] should use lowercase letter if your table name uses lowercase letter.

This is the case if you can't use SSH in your shared web server.

Answer (score 0):

If your are developed under Windows system and your application es running on *nix servers, check lower and upper case for your clasess and routes.

May be the name of your archive .php is different of your class

```
//file YourClassName.php

Class YourCassName {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the submodules?  Symfony1 works with submodules

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```